# Obtener valor de span anidado. jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo las siguientes lineas en una vista, donde `$_SESSION["usuario"]`, el nombre del usuario que ingreso

```
<div class="userCurrent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"];?></a></li>
       <li><a href="salir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Salir</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor del primero `li` en el `ul`, usando lo siguiente:

```
    var user;
    var dataUser = [];
    $('.currentUser').children('ul').children('li').each(function() {
        data.push($(this).children('span').text());
    });
    console.log(dataUser);
    user = dataUser[0];
```

pero me devuelve `undefined`, como puedo obtener ese valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del **each** haces referencia a  la variable **data** la cual no esta declarada de ahí que devuelve undefined, también te falto escalar luego del tag  **li** el tag  **a** ya que este contiene el span children, del cual quieres recuperar un texto que no hay, pero si pretendes recuperar el $_SESSION["usuario"], entonces debes obtener el text() del tag **a**.

Usando **bootstrap 3.4.0** y **jquery 3.4.1**, esto quedaría así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user;
    var dataSpan = [];
    var dataUser = [];
    $('.userCurrent').children('ul').children('li').each(function() {
        dataSpan.push($(this).children('a').children('span').text());
        //Recupera todo el texto dentro el tag a incluyendo el texto del tag span
        dataUser.push($(this).children('a').text()); 
    });
    console.log(dataSpan);
    console.log(dataUser);
    user = dataUser[0];
    console.log(user);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<script>
//Aqui va el script 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="userCurrent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">span1 </span>Usuario <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"];?></a></li>
       <li><a href="salir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">span2</span> Salir</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta obteniendo el `text` del `li`, ademas el `span` no tiene algún contenido por lo que te devolverá una cadena vacia

Ejemplo:

```
 var user;
    var dataUser = [];
    $('.currentUser ul li').each(function() {
        data.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(dataUser);
    user = dataUser[0];
```

en html agrega contenido a tu `span`

```
<div class="userCurrent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"><?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"];?></span> </a></li>
       <li><a href="salir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Salir</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: si, viendo bien el valor "esta" en  `a` y no en `span`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var user= <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"];?>;
</script>
```

puedes imprimirlo directamente o también usarlo guardando en localstorage.

```
<script>
    var user= <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"];?>;
    localStorage.setItem("user",user);
</script>
```

para cuando quieras obtenerlo desde cualquiera de tus paginas

```
localStorage.getItem("user");
```